# Unable to share wifi through ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet

I'm attempting to share my wifi connection from my Ubuntu computer to my raspberry pi through the ethernet port. I've tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work.

Right now I've created a wired connection, set it to "share to other computers" and "allow all users to connect', and then on my wifi connection I switched it to "allow all users.." and "shared to other computers". I really have no idea why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Enable IP forwarding. This is done either by using

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

After that add a rule telling to forward the traffic

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wifi0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wifi0 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Because you router do not known for your lan network we must do masquarade

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wifi0 -j MASQUERADE
```

NOTE: In example eth0 is name of nic card, wifi0 is name of your wifi card.
You can see card's names with command `ip a` or `ifconfig`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and solved it like this.

In the terminal type

`nm-connection-editor`

When it opens, select the wired connection item, clicking the edit button (the cog). In that menu, switch to the IPv4 tab, and select the method: 'shared to other computers'.

Then save the settings and it should work

from https://www.crookm.com/2018/05/sharing-wifi-connection-over-ethernet.html